# trying to create private member array, with size given from initializer list in C++(<vector> usage is forbidden)

Tags: c++, arrays, class, oop, object

So i'm trying to create a private member array on my School class where i'm going to be holding the address of some student objects. *My goal is to simulate the stusents entering the school building if the capacity of the building allows as such (think of the problem with small numbers)*  I have managed to implement the "address object part" but i have an issue concerning the size of the array. The variable which gives the size of the array is also a private member of the same class. That being said the compiler gives the error:

> error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘School::class_capacity’
>
> 148 |       Student* pointer_array[class_capacity];

Here's School class:

```
class School
{
    private:
      int class_capacity;
      Student* pointer_array[class_capacity];
   public:
        School(const int capacity)//constructor
      :class_capacity(capacity)
      {
        cout << "A New School has been created!" << endl;
      };
      ~School(){//destructor
        cout << "A School to be destroyed!" << endl;
      }; 
      void enter(Student* student, int stc=0/*student counter*/);
}
```

Student class is :

```
class Student 
{
private:
    string name;
    int no_floor;
    int no_classroom;
public:
    Student(const string& nam,int no_fl,int no_cla)//constructor
    : name(nam), no_floor(no_fl), no_classroom(no_cla)
    {
      cout << "A new student has been created! with name " << name << " heading to floor: "<< no_floor << " class: " << no_classroom << endl;
    };

    ~Student()//destructor
    {
      cout << "A Student to be destroyed! with name " << name << " is at "<< " class: " << no_classroom;

    };
```

Lastly my main where i allocate an array of pointers to Student objects.

```
int main(void)
{
//Student creation
       int i,floor,classroom;
       string stname;
       Student* students[5];
       for(i=0; i<5; i++)
       {
          cin >> stname;
          cin >> floor;
          cin >> classroom;
          students[i] = new Student(stname, floor, classroom);
       }
       for(i=0; i<5; i++)
       {
         delete students[i];
       }
}
```

And the enter function code:

```
void School::enter(Student* student, int stc/*student counter*/)
{
  pointer_array[stc] = student;
  (pointer_array[stc])->print();
  cout << " enters school!" << endl;
}
```

The array i'm trying to create in School class is meant to keep a pointer to already created Student objects on my main.
Does anybody know how to solve this? Again  library usage is forbidden

Comment: You probably don't want an array of pointers. I recommend going over your notes again. Come back when you've actually attempted something and run into a wall.

Comment: @sweenish hey there thanks for the answer! Unfortunately i do need one. :\ They just told me that it's either this or creating a list from scratch (without including std::list)

Comment: You cant define Variable Length Array (VLA) in C++ so also more precisely inside a class. VLA works inside functions for most compiler since this is `C` extension and compilers by default allow to mix C++ a C code. In C++ for runtime sized array use `std::vector`.

Comment: You want a `Student* pointer_to_array;` as the class member and then in the constructor you'll do `pointer_to_array = new Student[size_of_array_needed]`.  Then you'll also need to follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: I see literally no reason for an array of pointers, unless Student is a base class. I also don't like that `School` is both a school, and a class that manages a dynamic array. That should be split into two classes.

Comment: The instructor is outdated, teaching bad-practice. I would use `std::vector` as the primary standard solution, but you cannot use it now. You need to learn everything now - from memory management to RAII. I am sure that is not what your instructor demands. But that would be the right thing to do...

Comment: @NathanOliver thank you so much for the answer!! i will try it and come back for the results

Comment: @sweenish the actual program is.. a lot bigger. Trust me that's all the code you'll need for this problem. Just assume i have another class Student that is correctly implemented

Comment: @sweenish due to popular demand i added the Student class as well if you want to check it out!

Comment: And I still see zero reason for an array of pointers to Students. It should probably just be a dynamic array of Students. I also disagree with Red.Wave to an extent. This kind of knowledge is good for students to have, especially if we are in something like a Data Structures class where writing the dynamic array *is* the point of the assignment.

Comment: Why don't these courses just have you create a generic vector class, instead of disguising it as a `School` that's chock-full of pointers that are unnecessary?   I see assignments like  *You are to design an entire shopping mall and parking lot.  No vectors allows* -- Seriously, does that make *any* sense?

Comment: For what it's worth, that's exactly what I did in my class. All of my Data Structure assignments were to just mimic a chunk of the X data structure from the Standard Library, and grading was simply running the class through a test suite. In OOP, I still had little "themes" like what is seen here, but the grading was still to run the classes through a test suite. I think some profs do it this way because they feel it makes the assignment more "interesting." My take was that mimicking Standard Library behavior was interesting enough at the 400-level.

Comment: @sweenish Will have to agree. Anybody could use <vector> library and it would be easy then. So...What do you think would be the best thing to do in my case?

Comment: @ScatterBrainer See my first comment. The answers below will get you started, but you've shown no code to troubleshoot, just incomplete boilerplate. Per [ask] and [mre], this is still not what I'd consider a "good" question for this site.

Comment: @sweenish ok let me fix my question real quick

Comment: just posted the update

Comment: @ScatterBrainer `Student* pointer_array[class_capacity];` -- This is not legal C++, that's the bottom line.  Given that you have not accepted any of the answers so far, it is not clear what you are asking for.  A dynamic array of type `T` is done (in your case) by declaring a `T*` and at some point `T* x = new T[number_of_elements];` and later `delete [] x;` -- Other than that, what issue do you see with this?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I mean, OP's comments on answers below and the newer code posted are demonstrating a lack of knowledge at a foundational level. They're not outright saying it's for a class (I hope it's a class and not an interview), but my guess is that someone who has the link handy posts the good book link and close this as vague.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie trust me this question wouldn't be here if i was allowed to create a default constructor...If i incorprate this answer i'd have to go with something like T* x = new T("a name", a floor number, a class number). I don't want that. I don't want to create new objects, all i'm trying to do is create an array of pointers to the already existing objects. Do you have any ideas on how i could do it or even if what i'm writing above is completely off track? Thanks for the asnwer btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find the answer.The classes should look something like this.

School class:

```
class School
{
    private:
      int class_capacity;
      Student** pointer_array;
   public:
        School(const int capacity)//constructor
      :class_capacity(capacity)
      {
        pointer_array = new Student*[capacity];
        cout << "A New School has been created!" << endl;
      };
      ~School(){//destructor
        delete [] pointer_array;
        cout << "A School to be destroyed!" << endl;
      }; 
      void enter(Student* student, int stc=0/*student counter*/);
}
```

Class student , main and enter function stays as is.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie in case you wanted to see the solution to this ^

Answer (score 1):

Without using `std::vector` you'd need to do your own dynamic array management

```
class School
{
private:
    int class_capacity;
    Student* students;
public:
    School(const int capacity)//constructor
      :class_capacity(capacity)
    {
        students = new Student[capacity];
        cout << "A New School has been created!" << endl;
    };

    ~School(){//destructor
        delete[] students;
        cout << "A School to be destroyed!" << endl;
    }; 

    // Disable copying to avoid accidental double-deletion of array
    School(School const&) = delete;
    School& operator=(School const&) = delete;
};
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer! Truth be told since my actual code is huge i neglected to mention that Student class constructor has an initializer list. So please check the post again for the updated version. Again thanks for the time :)

Comment: Would the students need to be individually destroyed? If it's an array of pointers to students, my assumption is that those pointers were also dynamically allocated. I am not aware that deleting the dynamic array is sufficient.

Comment: @sweenish do you want me to post the main() too to see the full action? SInce the school is going to have many students i allocated an array of pointers to objects there.

Comment: This is why i was avoiding new/delete with the Student* pointer_array .. Because i want this array to be a pointer to the array of pointers to objects (the students) (i don't know if that makes sense)

Answer (score 0):

```
Student* pointer_array[class_capacity];
```

is not legal code since `class_capacity` is not known at compile time. You'll have to use a dynamically allocated array.

Use of `std::vector<Student>` will be appropriate most of the time. Since you are not allowed to use `std::vector`, your only option is to use

```
Student* student_array; // Not pointer_array.
```

as the member variable. Memory for the array can be allocated in the constructor.

```
   School(const int capacity) : class_capacity(capacity),
                                student_array(new Student[capacity]) {}
```

Please note that you need to follow [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) when you manage dynamic memory in your class.

---

**Update**, in response to OP's comment.

I would suggest adding a default constructor to `Student`.

```
// Default constructor, implemented using the other constructor.
Student() : Student("", 0, 0) {}
```

Comment: @R Sahu thanks for taking the time! The Student class actually has an initializer list itself .So not sure if i can do the new Student[capacity] code line

Comment: Did you see it?

Comment: Answer to the update: i tried this and they told me it was wrong because Student class takes a name as an input. So a default constructor is a "wrong approach". Thanks for taking the time though! :)

Comment: @ScatterBrainer, who's "they"?

Comment: @R Sahu the people i'm doing the project for

Comment: @ScatterBrainer, you can address too by using `char* student_array` and placement `new` but I think that goes beyond the scope of the issue in your original post.

Comment: @R Sahu char* ?  no pointer_array is an array of pointers not names. What do you mean?

Comment: @ScatterBrainer, lookup "placement new in C++" in your favorite search engine. Like I said, it goes beyond the scope of your original question.